# Handling whitespaces in http headers

Tags: http

Should leading or trailing whitespaces be ignored in an http request/response?

For example, should a HTTP/1.1 compliant client interpret this :

```
Connection  :   close      \r\n
```

as this :

```
Connection: close\r\n
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According with paragraph 4.2 of [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2) (HTTP/1.1), field values might be preceded by whitespace, but not the field name:

> Each header field consists
> of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names
> are case-insensitive. The field value may be preceded by any amount
> of LWS (linear white space), though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one SP or HT. Applications ought to follow "common form", where
> one is known or indicated, when generating HTTP constructs, since
> there might exist some implementations that fail to accept anything.

Comment: You are citing an 18 year old spec which has been obsoleted twice since.

Comment: You are right. I've update my answer to cite the current HTTP/1.1 specification (RFC2616), tough the content is barely the same.

Comment: RFC 2616 is a 16 year old spec which has been obsoleted once since.

Comment: Would you please be so kind to tell us what is the current RFC for the HTTP/1.1 specification, and if it has obsoleted anything about whitespace in the headers since RFC2068?

Comment: The current RFC is <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html>, and most of the text related to this has been rewritten from scratch. See <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.fields>.

Comment: OK. There I can read: "Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and optional trailing whitespace.". Nothing new, then. Thanks.

Comment: You are citing a 24-year-old specification which has been obsoleted twice since. The current RFC specification is [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-changes-from-rfc-7230). Still, no changes though: `field-name = token = 1*tchar`.

Answer (score 6):

See [RFC 7230 Appendix B. Collected ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#appendix-B)

```
header-field  = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS
field-value   = *( field-content / obs-fold )
field-content = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
field-vchar   = VCHAR / obs-text
```

`OWS` means optional whitespace, `field-value` includes whitespace too. You have to ignore leading and trailing whitespace somehow.

Leading whitespace is not a problem, but trailing whitespace breaks streaming design. You can't parse HTTP 1.1 header in a **pure streaming way** (without storing anything).

For example: `Connection: a    b \r\n b    c\r\n d \r\n`

You have received `a`, than whitespace. You can't remove this whitespace, because you don't know whether it is a part of `field-value` or `OWS`. So you have to store whitespace before receiving non-whitespace byte or `\r\n`. Same thing for `b` + whitespace + `c` and `d` + whitespace.

Popular streaming parsers like nginx/nodejs just stops header value after first whitespace. It means that these parsers are not 100% compatible with RFC 7230.

OBS folding was deprecated, but there are many old webservers that are capable to produce it. So you have to deal with whitespace hell in header value anyway.

The only one way to keep your parser working in pure streaming way is to provide whitespace to user as it is without trimming.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn’t, and it’s just plain invalid.

> - `tchar` = "`!`" / "`#`" / "`$`" / "`%`" / "`&`" / "`'`" / "`*`" / "`+`" / "`-`" / "`.`" / "`^`" / "`_`" / "`` ` ``" / "`|`" / "`~`" / `DIGIT` / `ALPHA`
> - `token` = 1*`tchar`
> - `field-name` = `token`
> - `header-field` = `field-name` "`:`" `OWS` `field-value` `OWS`

`field-name` cannot have spaces.

In `Connection  :   close      \r\n`, the `field-name` is `Connection`  , which is invalid.