# In php header giving bad gateway error. What to do?

Tags: php, header

```
<?php
/// Form validation

// if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
//     echo $_GET['email'];
//     echo $_GET['title'];
//     echo $_GET['ingredients'];
// }
// if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//     echo $_POST['email'];
//     echo $_POST['title'];
//     echo $_POST['ingredients'];
// }

$errors = array('email' => '', 'title' => '', 'ingredients' => '');
$email = $title = $ingredients = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    // echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    // echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['ingredients']);

    //Check email
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        // echo 'Email is empty <br>';
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is empty <br>';
    } else {
        // echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // echo "Email must be a valid email address";
            $errors['email'] = "Email must be a valid email address";
        }
    }

    //Check title
    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
        // echo 'Title is empty <br>';
        $errors['title'] =  'Title is empty <br>';
    } else {
        // echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $title)) {
            // echo 'Title must be letters and spaces only <br>';
            $errors['title'] =  'Title must be letters and spaces only <br>';
        }
    }

    //Check ingredients
    if (empty($_POST['ingredients'])) {
        // echo 'Ingredients is empty <br>';
        $errors['ingredients']  = 'Ingredients is empty <br>';
    } else {
        // echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['ingredients']);
        $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
        if (!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)(,\s*[a-zA-Z\s]*)*$/', $ingredients)) {
            // echo 'Ingredients must be comma separated <br>';
            $errors['ingredients']  = 'Ingredients must be comma separated <br>';
        }
    }
}
if (array_filter($errors)) {
    echo 'There is error';
} else {
    header('Location : project/index.php');
}
//End of check form

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php include 'project/header.php' ?>
<section class="container grey-text">
    <h4 class="center">Add a Pizza</h4>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="white" method="post">
        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
        <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['email']; ?></div>
        <label for="title">Pizza Title</label>
        <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['title']; ?></div>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>">
        <label for="ingredients">Ingredients (comma separetd):</label>
        <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['ingredients']; ?></div>
        <input type="text" name="ingredients" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ingredients); ?>">
        <div class="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<?php include 'project/footer.php' ?>


</html>
```

When I am redirecting my PHP file it shows me the below text:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.28 Server at localhost Port 80

Now how to solve this error.

Comment: _"More information about this error may be available in the server error log."_, is there?

Comment: The location in your header should be an URL, it looks more like a file path. Remember that this header is send to the browser as an instruction to load another page.

Comment: I'm guessing it is probably due to the space between `Location` and the following colon. [That does _not_ belong there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773856/1427878), so remove it.